# Microsecond loss with coma-separated locale

Tags: php, datetime

Could someone explains me why PHP DateTime constructor ignore microseconds when using a local with coma as decimal separator?

```
$date = new \DateTime('2017-07-29T13:57:27.123456Z');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u e');
echo "\n";

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr'); // or any locale with coma as decimal separator

$date = new \DateTime('2017-07-29T13:57:27.123456Z');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u e');
```

Outputs:

```
2017-07-29 13:57:27.123456 Z
2017-07-29 13:57:27.000000 Z
```

Sounds to me like a PHP bug. Is there a work-around for this?

Important: to reproduce, you need to install and use a locale with coma as decimal separator. If you run `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr')` but have not a fr locale installed, the `setlocale` has no effect.

PS: I cannot use createFromFormat. Because I extend DateTime and need this in my constructor, I would need a solution that does not use DateTime static methods.

Thanks,

Comment: when I run your code it outputs fine as expected

Comment: I can't duplicate it: https://3v4l.org/MQpQW

Comment: You must install and use a locale with coma decimal separator. If fr locale is nost installed, then, you run twice the same code. See setlocale does not works: https://3v4l.org/Gqcmu

Comment: It is a PHP bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67127

Comment: @FelippeDuarte interesting. I thought I had replicated it. I'm probably wrong then.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the locale decimal formatting. `fr_FR` has `,`. Try it with `en_GB` or `en_US` (which have `.`) and it will show microseconds; try it with `de_DE`, `it_IT`, or `bg_BG` (which have `,` as well), and it won't show them.

```
% cat en_GB/LC_NUMERIC
. # <--- decimal separator - microseconds
,
3;3

% cat en_US/LC_NUMERIC
. # <--- decimal separator - microseconds
,
3;3

% cat it_IT/LC_NUMERIC
, # <--- decimal separator - no microseconds
.
0;0

% cat de_DE/LC_NUMERIC
, # <--- decimal separator - no microseconds

-1

% cat fr_FR/LC_NUMERIC
, # <--- decimal separator  - no microseconds

-1

% cat bg_BG/LC_NUMERIC
, # <--- decimal separator  - no microseconds

3;3
```

So the solution is to set your decimal separator to `.` for your french locale, which obviously will break everything else.

---

Like @FelippeDuarte said in the comments, it seems to be a known bug: [PHP Bug #67127](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67127). You can read more about the problem there. People there are still figuring out:

> I can confirm this issue. The culprit is in timelib_get_frac_nr()
>   where strtod() is used[1], which is locale dependend. Using
>   zend_strtod() instead would solve the issue, but that would make
>   timelib depending on the Zend engine, what is certainly not
>   desired.

Comment: Set the decimal operator to `.` can be a valid work-around for me if it can be done in runtime and if there is a solution to "restore" the initial separator after the date creation. However the zend dependency is not possible as I develop a very wide-used library.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @FelippeDuarte it seems to be a known bug (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67127) and seems not possible to change only the decimal separator, the `LC_NUMERIC` locale should be changed and restored. The most widely supported locale with dot separator is `C`.

So it seems there is no better work-around that:

```
if (strpos((string) .1, '.') === false) {
    $locale = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, '0');
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');
}
$date = new \DateTime('2017-07-29T13:57:27.123456Z');
if (isset($locale)) {
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, $locale);
}

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u e');
```